# C# write textfile from google calendar api

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I need some help. Probably it is easy, but I don't get it.
In our firestation is a screen where the alerts are shown (address, keyword, ...). When there is no alert I'd like to show upcoming events like birthdays, etc. The software running the screen needs ".txt"-files for input.
 So what I want to do is: I create a google calendar and put all the events in it. Every night the task scheduler runns a little piece of software and downloads the events from google, writes everything in one file and the alert-software reads this file.

Until now I got so far:

- I created a google calendar api.
- I downloaded a code sample from google and got it working with two calendars.

And that's it. Now I got stuck all day long and I guess I'm a better firefighter than programmer. So I need help. Please give me some hints how to do it.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalendarQuickstart
{
  class Program
   {
    static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API Quickstart";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request. CALENDAR
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = 10;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
        // END REQUEST

        // Define parameters of request. BIRTHDAY
        EventsResource.ListRequest request1 = service.Events.List("#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com");
        request1.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request1.ShowDeleted = false;
        request1.SingleEvents = true;
        request1.MaxResults = 10;
        request1.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
        // END REQUEST


        // List events. CALENDAR
        Events events = request.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
        if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
            {
                string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                {
                    when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
            }
        } // END LISTE

        // List events. BIRTHDAY
        Events events1 = request1.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
        if (events1.Items != null && events1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var eventItem in events1.Items)
            {
                string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                {
                    when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
            }
        } // END LISTE

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
        }
        Console.Read();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a `List<String>` object (possibly named `ListOfLines`, initially empty, and then go on adding one string for each line you'd like your file to have. Then, when you already have all your lines in the list (in appropriate order), you just use `File.WriteAllLines(filename, ListOfStrings)`, and a file will be created with the given filename, whose lines will be the strings in the list.

From what I have seen, you'd just replace `Console.Writeline(somestring)` by `ListOfLines.Add(somestring)` on your current code.
Also, mind that you don't need to explicitly add a newline to your strings, `File.WriteLines` does that for you.